# Using display table-cell to set all elements to equal height

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on some cross browser compatibility (mainly making my site display properly in IE).

On one page I have `<figure>`s repeating and I want their height to all be the same. I was told that using `display: table-cell` would do this, so my markup looks like this:

```
<div class="table-container">
    <div id="projects">
        <figure>

        </figure>
        <figure>

        </figure>
        <figure>

        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

My stylesheet (ie.css) looks like this:

```
html[data-page-id="code"] #code .table-container {
    display: table;
}
html[data-page-id="code"] #projects {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-row;
}
    html[data-page-id="code"] #projects figure {
        float: left;
        display: table-cell;
        width: 290px;
        background: #c1c1c1;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    }
```

The columns still don't equalize and the person who suggested I use this refuses to tell me why.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZ4Y3/)

Answer (score 0):

`float : left` isn't helpful here, as floated elements wind up with `display : block`. To get `display : table-cell` to work correctly, remove the float, then add `border-collapse : separate` and `border-spacing : 0 10px 30px 10px` to the `display : table` element.

Here's a variation on your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/cZ4Y3/1/).

Comment: I've seen no change at all

Comment: In which browser version? I see three different height boxes in your version of the fiddle and 3 identical height boxes with my version.

Comment: The jsfiddle works, but when I view my page in IE9, I see no difference, hang on, I'll upload and post you a link

Comment: It looks to me like there's a bunch going on on that site that doesn't really come up with the simpler example. I can get the display : table-cell to work, but there are quite a few side-effects. Is explicitly setting the height an option?

Comment: Guess it wouldn't hurt to do that. I just consider it a last resort because I know it's bad practice